Molecular Foundation of Evolution
I would like to get the permission to use the figure displayed in connection with the question: Why would the brain flip the images perceived by your eyes? for my upcoming article on the Molecular Foundation of Evolution to be published in the Advances of Quantum Chemistry later this year.
It strikes a very nice primitive chord, which I would like to convey.
Who do I ask?
With best regards
Erkki Brändas
Editor Advances in Quantum Chemistry

I've migrated this to Meta. This is an interesting post and good you ask. @StevenJeuris might well have drawn the picture himself - in that case, he owns copyright. He hasn't cited sources so I guess it's from his own hand. In that case he'll be the one to deal with, as image copyrights are not transferred to Imgur or to the SE team afaik

Having said that, this may have to be dealt with at Stack Meta.

Out of interest, what will the article be about? :)

@StevenJeuris It'll be about mirroring subjective high-level perceptions of 'up' and 'down' back onto a clump of gray matter filled with cells that have no clue what up and down means and asking how the image is flipped, blatantly disregarding the fact that babies learn to distinguish up from down by multimodal processing by incorporating and linking visual perceptions to touch, basically by grabbing everything they see and stuff it into their mouths :)

The article is a follow up on a recent one "Molecular Theory of the Genetic Code", published in Molecular Physics, Open Access https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00268976.2018.1471227      It deals, in addition to the upside-down paradox, also with the Necker Cube- and the Dancing Silhouette Illusion. If you can find the artist, please let me know.

I believe the image came from the article I linked to originally, which now no longer is available: http://www.newscientist.com/blog/lastword/2008/05/eye-level.html
Doing an image search on Google might help you with finding who held original copyright.
Given the simplicity of the image, you could of course just redraw it yourself or ask someone with minimally artistic skills to draw it.
Sorry I can't be of any more help. Best of luck!

Awww the disappointment... I really thought you drew that yourself :-)
